# Basic Stripe integration fails to load the payment page

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am using the server quickstart example to send a user to Stripe to make payment

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/server

The required session id is returned and I am sending it to Stripe. Yet the payment page does not load.

I have swapped my API key for XXXXX.

Set PHP to show all error, and none exist.

Triple checked that my code matches the integration example (with the obvious required modifications)

Checked my Stripe account.

In HEAD

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
```

In PHP

```
require_once('stripe-php-6.31.5/init.php');

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("pk_test_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

$object = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
        'success_url' => 'https://www.example.com/success',
        'cancel_url' => 'https://www.example.com/cancel',
        'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
        'line_items' => [[
        'amount' => 500,
        'currency' => 'gbp',
        'name' => 'T-shirt',
        'description' => 'Comfortable cotton t-shirt',
        'images' => ['https://www.example.com/t-shirt.png'],
        'quantity' => 1,
    ]]
]);

$session_id = $object->id;

if ($session_id) {

    echo "<script>
          var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
          stripe.redirectToCheckout({
          sessionId: '{{" . $session_id . "}}'
          }).then(function (result) {
          });
          </script>";

} else {

    echo 'No Session ID!';

}
```

The Stripe payment page should load.

Additionally, the javascript once I have the session_id looks like this

```
stripe.redirectToCheckout({
                sessionId: 
'{{cs_KmeIFgWSfN5GW6tP2e5IQ0Vb9EA0q3pWGHZNoDfFKAdcc6kW7DwsM6dAbhQ30}}'
            }).then(function (result) {
                // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
                // error, display the localized error message to your customer
                // using `result.error.message`.
            });
```

The user then seems this page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>KP Balance and Purchase</title>
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

    <script>
        <!--
        function checkout(session_id) {

            var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_yLz5iASFgRnotoAQc79miQGz');

            stripe.redirectToCheckout({
                sessionId: '{{cs_KmeIFgWSfN5GW6tP2e5IQ0Vb9EA0q3pWGHZNoDfFKAdcc6kW7DwsM6dAbhQ30}}'
            }).then(function (result) {
                // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
                // error, display the localized error message to your customer
                // using `result.error.message`.
            });

            }

        //-->
</script>

</head>
<body>

<form>
    <input type="button" onclick="checkout()" value="Buy Now!" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is your JavaScript executing correctly? What happens if you echo in a `console.log` call there?

Comment: What does happen? What does your browser devtools show? The sample code on the Stripe docs you link to describe showing error msgs using `result.error.message` in the `.then()` function, adding that might show the problem?

Comment: When the javascript is executed the browser is redirected to Stripe, in the console I am now seeing the error "Uncaught Error: apiKey or pageIdentifier/sessionIdentifier is not set", but my javascript does contain the session id.

Comment: `{{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}}` is usually used to signal “this is a placeholder” in technical documentation, but that does not mean you’re supposed to include the curly braces in the actual value. Pretty sure your `sessionId: '{{cs_KmeI…Q30}}'` should actually be just `sessionId: 'cs_KmeI…Q30'`

Comment: Not sure if I should laugh or cry. That was it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Additionally, the javascript once I have the session_id looks like this

```
stripe.redirectToCheckout({
                sessionId: '{{cs_KmeIFgWSfN5GW6tP2e5IQ0Vb9EA0q3…kW7DwsM6dAbhQ30}}'
```

`{{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}}` is usually used to signal “this is a placeholder” in technical documentation, but that does not mean you’re supposed to include the curly braces in the actual value.

Your `sessionId: '{{cs_KmeI…Q30}}'` should actually be just `sessionId: 'cs_KmeI…Q30'` here.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this for days and even put a request into Stripe for assistance. I finally got it to work.

**NO curly brackets** but also **NO quotes**. **JUST the variable name** you(we) assigned to the variable given when the server replies. This is, the `id` value of the array returned from `\Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([..])`

From your example, it will be the `session_id` in **PHP** and `sessionId` in the **JS**. This means your `sessionId: '{{cs_KmeI…Q30}}'` should actually be just `sessionId: 'cs_KmeI…Q30'`.

Whoopi .. loaded the checkout page FINALLY! :O)

EDIT:  Sorry but it was the end of a 14hr work day. My eyes hurt and I had a headache from them. Good morning all.

One doesn't want to put an actual hard coded session id value in single quotes as the session is volatile. Once that session expires or a different one for a different payment is initiated then using 'examp123le0fID' will not work. So we want to use an assigned dynamic value. That variable should not be enclosed in anything- no curlies, no quotes.

On the initialization of payment file I created a variable for the session id using the array that Stripe returns to us. This I did in PHP, as that is what I am using for this section of code. I then added a script after the body section that assigned that value(variable) to a new java variable. Immediately after that I added a script that passed the java variable to the java file containing the Stripe java redirect code. Inside it I assigned that variable to a new name using const which was then passed to the redirect code itself. This may be the long way to do it. I am not good at java, Jason, Ajax, etc and haven't been doing any real programming for over 10 years but the important thing is this approach worked for us.

So on our donation.php file we have:

```
                           $session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
                            'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
                            'line_items' => [[
                              'name' => 'Custom t-shirt',
                              'description' => 'Your custom designed t-shirt',
                              'amount' => 5000, /* order.amount */
                              'currency' => 'usd',
                              'quantity' => 1,
                            ]],
                            'success_url' => 'https://example.com/success',
                            'cancel_url' => 'https://example.com/cancel',
                          ]);

                        $stripeSession = array($session);
                        $sessId = ($stripeSession[0]['id']);
```

Then immediately after the end of body in the same file I put this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var ssId = "<?php echo $sessId ?>";</script> 

<script src="./client.js"></script>
```

where client is the js file containing the Stripe redirect code. Inside that file we had this:

```
const stripe = Stripe('pk_test_UKRcYdXTmraCEZspx8PE7NzB00QZyoUXp3');
const checkout_Id = (ssId);
```

and the Stripe redirect:

```
 stripe.redirectToCheckout({
 sessionId: checkout_Id,
   });
```

And that returned the full page checkout form with payment section.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please, take your time to explain your answer. You got negative votes because your explanation was not clear. I took me a long time to understand and edit your answer. Also, read more about [How to answer a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you explain this scripts more clearly please. Because I'm just working the same example and don't get it how it works if I see that snipets of code. But I believe it works probably.

Comment: This is the perfect solution. Thank you very much for that !