# Stripe redirectToCheckout with Laravel 6/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, laravel, stripe-payments

I'm trying `stripe.redirectToCheckout` in Laravel 6. And it's been days now, I can't find anything helpful on internet. I used strip documentation for creating a user session and redirectToCheckout and implemented stripe session in web/routes and `redirectToCheckout` in JavaScript.

The following is the button for pay with stripe

```
<button id="checkout-button"
    data="{{$id}}" href="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"
    role="link" style="width: 100%"
    class="btn btn-dark">Pay with stripe
</button>
```

The following is the JavaScript function for redirectToCheckout

```
<script>
    (function () {
        var stripe = window.Stripe('pk_test_ZuGUA3XxCsWvZVbqnOkFMQnM00PV2c0Acm');
        var checkoutButton = document.getElementById('checkout-button');

        checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
            // When the customer clicks on the button, redirect
            // them to Checkout.
            console.log('button clicked');
            var product_name = document.getElementById('#p_name');
            var product_price = document.getElementById('#p_price');
            var name, price;
            // var checkout_btn = document.getElementById('#checkout-button-plan_GI1dhi4ljEzk0R');
            btn = $(this).attr('data');
            console.log(btn);

            stripe.redirectToCheckout({
                items: [
                    // Replace with the ID of your SKU
                    {sku: 'sku****', quantity: 1}
                ],
                successUrl: 'http://4c655de9.ngrok.io/success',
                cancelUrl: 'http://4c655de9.ngrok.io/canceled',
                clientReferenceId: btn
            }).then(function (result) {
                console.log('result');
                // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
                // error, display the localized error message to your customer
                // using `result.error.message`.
                console.log(result.error.message);

            });
        });
    })();
</script>
```

The following is the web/route.php function for `\Stripe\Checkout\Session`

```
Route::get('/', function () {

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk****');

$session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
    'success_url' => 'http://4c655de9.ngrok.io/success',
    'cancel_url' => 'http://4c655de9.ngrok.io/canceled',
    'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
    'line_items' => [
        [
            'name' => 'T-shirt',
            'description' => 'Comfortable cotton t-shirt',
            'amount' => 1500,
            'currency' => 'usd',
            'quantity' => 2,
        ],
    ],
]);
$id = $session->id;
return view('home')->with('id', $id);
```

Comment: Please post the code as text, not as images.

Comment: Would you care to answer, sir?

Comment: Where is your `sessionId`? in your redirect you don't provide the sessionId. `stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: '<?= $id ?>', items: [{.....` You do provide is as the home view, `$id = $session->id;
return view('home')->with('id', $id);` Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56213377/1356107

Comment: Yes, I did. I have successfully integrated stipe checkout with laravel. I will post it here later today.